# Is it possible to use boost.any as a key in a std::map(or something similiar)?

Tags: c++, boost

`std::map<any, string>` is not working so I wonder if there's another approach to
have arbritary keys?

Comment: how can I post templateparameters ins stackoverflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is not with `Boost::Any`, but rather with the fact that you are not specifying a custom comparator. Since `map` is a sorted associative container, you need to have a comparator.

The following works for me: tailor it according to your purposes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

using namespace std;    
struct cmp {
    bool operator()(const boost::any& l, const boost::any& r) {
        try
        {
            int left = boost::any_cast<int>(l);
            int right = boost::any_cast<int>(r);
            return left < right;
        }
        catch(const boost::bad_any_cast &)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
int main() {   
    map<boost::any, string, cmp> ma;
     boost::any to_append = 42;
     ma.insert(std::make_pair(to_append, "int"));
    if (ma.find(42) != ma.end()) {
        cout << "hurray!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your comparison functor isn't valid for use in a map because it can return false for both a < b and b < a for some (a, b) pairs.

Comment: An example would be nice. Anyway, I do think more such cases can be constructed where the comparator will fail. The very idea of having an ordering across types doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: An example would be any any pair where one (a) contains and int and the other (b) contains a string. Your comparator would return false for a<b and b<a.
I guess you could fix this by converting both any objects to a string (id they're streamable), but then you might as well use string as a key...

Comment: Thanks for the example. I did have this in mind. The point is, you cannot compare across types. So, ...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at `boost::variant` rather than `boost::any`, so you can be sure all the types you are using are comparable.

Using visitors would be the best way to provide a comparison operator for `variant`s.

Answer (score -1):

Use if(any.type() == other.type())